# Javascript pass by reference

Tags: javascript

How can I capture the value of an object at the current state of the line of code and use that value later instead of the reference?

How can I keep the value of myRows as 1 so I can use it for comparison??

```
var myRows= this.grid.getSelectedRows();  // 1
var newRows= myRows;

  //run some logic to add 8 to newRows


 alert(myRows)  // 9

 alert(newRows)  //9
```

Comment: What does `getSelectedRows` return?

Comment: if myRows != 1 in your alert, then you must of changed it in your some logic or else it would still be 1 assuming getSelectedRows returns 1

Comment: I don't see how "pass by reference" has anything to do with this; there are no values being "passed" anywhere, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: alert myrows at the top too.

Comment: @RocketHazmat The comment says `1`

Comment: @Ian: "How can I keep the value of myRows as 1"

Comment: @RocketHazmat I could've sworn that's how I read it the first time, but I kept re-reading it and confused myself.

Comment: @Ian: If that's the case, then this makes no sense.  I was wondering if it was an object, an array, or actually a number.

Comment: What does `console.log(myRows)` show you?  Is it an array or an object?  Or is it a number?

Comment: Show us the "some logic" part. If myRows was 1 string or number and your 'some logic' did not change it, then the alert should show 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that you make a *deep copy* of your JavaScript object.
This is usually referred to as *cloning* an object.

See [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) on various methods how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy each of the attributes of the object recursively.

The easiest way is to just use some framework like lodash or angularjs.